# Old anime movie about an alien who falls in love with a human girl

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching it on TV when I was young, but I don't know the title. It's about creatures that are not actually aliens, but are not human either. One of them creates an illusory world for the girl he likes, and pretends that he was the guy the girl liked.

Comment: "when I was young" doesn't give us any clues whatsoever. We don't know how old you are.